# mysql "group by" very slow query

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-optimization

I have this query in a table with about 100k records, it runs quite slow (3-4s), when I take out the group it's much faster (less than 0.5s). I'm quite at loss what to do to fix this:

```
SELECT msg.id,
       msg.thread_id,
       msg.senderid,
       msg.recipientid, 
       from_user.username AS from_name,
       to_user.username AS to_name
FROM msgtable AS msg
LEFT JOIN usertable AS from_user ON msg.senderid = from_user.id
LEFT JOIN usertabe AS to_user ON msg.recipientid = to_user.id
GROUP BY msg.thread_id
ORDER BY msg.id desc
```

msgtable has indexes on `thread_id`, `id`, `senderid` and `recipientid`.

explain returns:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  msg ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    162346  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  from_user   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.msg.senderid 1    
1   SIMPLE  to_user eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   db.msg.recipientid  1
```

Any ideas how to speed this up while returning the same result (there are multiple messages per thread, i want to return only one message per thread in this query).

thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `usertable` indexes? Can you please run `EXPLAIN <query>` and post the results?

Comment: Typically, you have to declare all columns mentioned in the SELECT that are not encapsulated by aggregate functions (COUNT, SUM, MIN, MAX, etc) in the GROUP BY.  Would `DISTINCT` serve you better in this situation?

Comment: Why the left join?  Wouldn't each message require a recipient and sender?

Comment: Yes a message would require a recipient and sender, hence left join not required.

Comment: Also, paste the output of `show create table msgtable`.

Comment: @Sherif Buzz when you reply to comments, like the one where on added `EXPLAIN` you can tag the people that asked using @Frankie @OMG Ponies so that they know something new is up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
select m.thread_id, m.id, m.senderid, m.recipientid, 
       f.username as from_name, t.username as to_name
from msgtable m
join usertable f on m.senderid = f.id
join usertable t on m.recipientid = t.id
where m.id = (select MAX(id) from msgtable where thread_id = m.thread_id)
```

Or this:

```
select m.thread_id, m.id, m.senderid, m.recipientid, 
       (select username from usertable where id = m.senderid) as from_name,
       (select username from usertable where id = m.recipientid) as to_name
from msgtable m
where m.id = (select MAX(id) from msgtable where thread_id = m.thread_id)
```

Why were the user tables left joined?  Can a message be missing a from or to?..

Comment: Thanks a million, I tried both options - first option about 1.5s, second option about 2s. anything else i can do to bring it down more ?

Comment: @Sherif well, do you really need ALL of the threads at once?...  Is there a datetime column that could be used to cut down on the required data?

Comment: @Forsco, actually this query is translated into is a select count(*) of query by a paging class - yes i need all threads as this is for an admin function...

Comment: @Sherif so do you need the real data or just the count?  Or is the result cached and then paginated?

Comment: @Sherif Ok, just checking.  Glad we were able to cut the time down, not sure I could do much more for you.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem is that you have no usable indexes on `msgtable`. Create an index on *at least* `senderid` and `recipientid`, and it should help the speed of your query, as it will limit the number of results needing to be scanned.